# Use constants or fields in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit

While writing unit tests I keep running into the same question all the time. Consider the following classes:

```
class Dog {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}

public class MyTest {

    private static final Dog DOG = createDog();
    private static final String DOG_NAME = "rex";
    private static final int DOG_AGE = 3;

    private static Dog createDog() {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName(DOG_NAME);
        dog.setAge(DOG_AGE);
        return dog;
    }

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        SomeObject outcome = classUnderTest.doSomething(DOG);

        assertThat(outcome.getName(), is(DOG_NAME));
        assertThat(outcome.getAge(), is(DOG_AGE));
    }

}

public class MyTest2 {

    private static final String DOG_NAME = "rex";
    private static final int DOG_AGE = 3;

    private Dog dog;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        dog = createDog();
    }

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        SomeObject outcome = classUnderTest.doSomething(DOG);

        assertThat(outcome.getName(), is(DOG_NAME));
        assertThat(outcome.getAge(), is(DOG_AGE));
    }

    private Dog createDog() {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName(DOG_NAME);
        dog.setAge(DOG_AGE);
        return dog;
    }

}
```

Is it better to hold the dog as a constant or as a field? If this question is just opinion based I will close it.

Comment: If your dog is mutable (it has setters), it's not a constant. I would prefer to make it a local variable, since having it as a member variable (static or otherwise) means that you can accidentally have state hanging around that you didn't intend to use.

Comment: Well, the setUp method get's called before every test, so I can't run in such a state.

Comment: @AndyTurner agreed in general. But JUnit creates a new instance of the test class before each test method, and calls the setUp() method before each test method. So the state, even stored as a field, is only usable by a single test method. That's the classical way of creating a common test fixture. Using static mutable state is wrong, since the order of the tests might change the outcome: tests are not independant anymore.

Comment: Yes, but I made it static final fields!

Comment: Static final doesn't mean constant.

Comment: @JBNizet What I have tended to find is that you use the same dog value in most cases only - there are always one or two cases where you want something different. You can just create a local variable in those cases, but then you have two instances hanging around, and only use 1. I find that it's cleaner to make it a local variable in all cases, so that you can't accidentally refer to the wrong instance. OTOH, this means that failures in dog creation would be reported as test failure, rather than setup failure. YMMV.

Comment: @AndyTurner static final makes a field constant!

Comment: @Chris311 No test can replace DOG by another dog, because DOG is final. But they all can change the name or age of DOG by calling DOG.setName() and DOG.setAge(). So, if one test relies on DOG's name to be rex, but is executed after a test that changes DOG's name to Mirza, you're doomed.

Comment: @JBNizet How can they change it if it is final?

Comment: final only makes the field final. It only prevents you from affecting a new value to MyTest.DOG. But it doesn't make the state of the Dog object immutable. So, you may not do `MyTest.DOG = new Dog()`, but you may do `MyTest.DOG.setName("Mirza")`.

Comment: final does not make the object itself immutable. If you have a List stored in an final field, you can still change its contents. Your dog would only then be immutable if every single field in DOG was final too AND these values are not a mutable Object.

Comment: @Chris311 "Every constant is a static final field, but not all static final fields are constants." [Read more in the Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common pattern when running test... you need data! There are a few options

- Copy paste (as you showed)
- [Object Mother](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) pattern.
- Or the sweet [Test Data Builder](http://natpryce.com/articles/000714.html) Pattern.

The idea with the Test Data Builder Pattern is that you **only** reference and make explicit information that is relevant to the test.

And since you're using Java, there's a tiny framework called [Make It Easy](https://github.com/npryce/make-it-easy) that simplifies the creation of these builders... and there's an intellij plugin that auto-generates the builders using Make it easy, so with just a shortcut, you'll have all set up.

Now, answering your question: A consequence of this pattern, is that you'll rarely need to have data as constants in your tests. You want to make your test as explicit as possible, rather than add layers of indirection... So the answer is neither a constant nor a field, but a local variable in the test itself.

Comment: What if you got more than just one test which needs the same dog. Will you create/build this dog in every single test as a local variable?

Comment: @Chris311 yes, that's the idea. And I assume that each test would need a slightly different Dog instance, so you can tailor the instance in the test itself. If I look at the code you posted, using this pattern would add a class (the builder) and remove everything from the test class, except the actual method annotated with `@Test`.

Comment: Ok, think of the following situation: You want to feed the dog. So you mock a method called feeder.feed(dog, food). You want to feed different dogs always with the same food. So food never changes. Assume there would be a FoodBuilder. How would you define food? Still a local variable for every test?

Comment: @Chris311 I think in that case I would instantiate the dog on each test (as they are different) and for the food, I might set that as an attribute on the test, but I don't fully like the idea (because it introduces a layer of indirection, which means that the test is harder to understand). If this feels hard to do, it might be pointing at an issue with the design... just mentioning as it's good to remember that tests help to find design problems  :).

Comment: Sometimes the layer of indirection isn't a bad thing. Sometimes you just name a constant DOG_FOOD if it doesn't matter which dog food.